# Registering user with AppAuth

Tags: android, openid-connect, appauth

I am working with AppAuth to implement SSO in my app.  I have implemented logging the user in with AppAuth and the Auth Intent.  I am now looking at registering users via the AppAuth SDK.  Does AppAuth support the registering of users?

I appreciate this is a little ambiguous however, I had made an assumption that registration would also be handled through AppAuth but I can't find documentation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registration is a feature of the Identity Provider and you don't code it in the client app, so it will never be a feature of AppAuth. There are two options that are most commonly used:

- A login screen can offer a self sign up feature as in the 'Create Account' option in the below image. This makes sense when your app deals with personal assets of the end user. You should not need to write any code to make this work.
- Alternatively users may need to be provisioned by an administrator, if the app deals with corporate assets that do not belong to the user. This is typically managed by your back end components, which might call a [SCIM 2.0 endpoint](https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/system-admin-guide/data-sources/scim.html#scim-2-0https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/system-admin-guide/data-sources/scim.html#scim-2-0) to create the user.

[image]